# Reload html inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

Inside the body of my **index.html** I have a graph (created with d3.js) and the following code that show a stepper that has as many steps as there are child nodes of the clicked node:

```
  <div ng-include="ctrl.numlab==2 && 'views/stepper-two-labs.html' || 'views/stepper-three-labs.html'"></div>
```

So I have the two html pages: **stepper-two-labs.html** and **stepper-three-labs.html**

The function that loads the contents of the stepper is as follows:

```
var click = function (d){
       vm.numlab=d.children.length;
          $(document).ready(function(){
          for(var i=0; i<d.children.length; i++) {
            var lab=d.children[i].name;
            $('#iframe'+i).attr('src', 'http://localhost:18181/lab/use/NS/'+lab);
          }
      });
}
```

And load the appropriate content inside the stepper .html (stepper-two-labs.html and stepper-three-labs.html)

When I click on a node that has 2 child nodes it loads the stepper with 2 steps and when I finish, if I click on a new node with 3 child nodes it loads the stepper with 3 steps. If, on the other hand, I click on a node that has the same number of child nodes as the previous one, the html does not load again and therefore the content is updated but does not start from the initial step because the page is not loaded from the beginning since is used the same .html page (since the number of child nodes is the same). So I look for a method to solve this problem and maybe update the div inside the index.html with every click.

Comment: You for sure need to remove `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: no, the problem persists :/

Comment: I did not say it would fix it. but you DO not need that there

Answer (score 0):

You could try to first add a empty source to the iframe and then adding the link you want to this way force the iframe to refresh.

```
    var click = function (d){
       vm.numlab=d.children.length;
          $(document).ready(function(){
          for(var i=0; i<d.children.length; i++) {
            var lab=d.children[i].name;
            $('#iframe'+i).attr('src', '');
            $('#iframe'+i).attr('src', 'http://localhost:18181/lab/use/NS/'+lab);
          }
      });
```

Comment: the problem persists

Comment: maybe try this line after you change the src.
document.getElementById("iframe"+i).contentDocument.location.reload(true);